# z-index is not working with pdf in iframe

Tags: c#, asp.net

[image]I am opening a pdf file in my page under an iframe.it's working fine in other browsers except internet explorer.In internet explorer the top menu of my page is going behid the iframe.I tried z-index but it doesn't work for me.Can any one please help me? 
Here is my Master Page Code :

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
         <div id="wrapper" class="mywrapper">
            <!-- Navigation -->
            <!-- Fixed navbar -->
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" style="position:relative;z-index:2;">
              ......
            </nav>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="navbar-default sidebar" role="navigation">                   
                        <div class="sidebar-nav">
                           ...................
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.sidebar-collapse -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.navbar-static-side -->
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-lg-9" style="background-color: #FFF; z-index:1;" >
                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
                    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                </div>
            </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Here is my Content aspx Page

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">
    <br />

        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9" style="height:1000px;">
            <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" id="pdf" src="abc.pdf" style="position:relative;z-index:1;" ></iframe>    
        </div>    

</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Is iframe has ability to show pdf file?

Comment: yes it's showing the pdf file very fine but on the top of the page there is a navigation menu with dropdown.the dropdown menu is opening behind the iframe :(

Comment: I've added snapshot you can see that

Comment: Oh, right, I have tried it and it seems this is browser compatibility case..

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mtoha/h02ggcg5/
When I open using UC Browser, overlap is good. When I try using IE 11, that is not working

Comment: Can you please suggest me the solution :(

Comment: No clue, I am not expert web designer..